# How do I extract latitude and longitude coordinates from the page source of an AWS map?

Tags: r, screen-scraping

I have the page source for a map that is displayed on AWS. It looks like the code pasted below. There are thousands of these.

The other information would be good too, but at the very least I want to extract the latitude and longitude coordinates from them and put them in two columns that I can use for analysis.

How can I do this? I usually use R.

```
    {
        pos: {
          lat: 37.65280312142619,
          lng: 140.94978332519534
        },
        title: "福島県11例目",
        icon: 'image/inpatient_icon4.04.png',
        infoWindowOpen: false,
        infoWindowContent: '<head><a id="num_start" href="https://www.mhlw.go.jp/content/10906000/000618993.pdf">福島県11例目</a></head><body><strong><div class="container"><div class="item">・4/04</div><div class="item">福島県発表 / 相双保健所管内居住</div></div></strong><div class="container"><div class="item">&nbsp;※追記</div><div class="item">無症状 / 福島県9例目の濃厚接触者</div></div></body><footer><div><span style=color:black>現在 </span>入院中</div><div id="num_end"><span style=color:black>濃厚接触者</span> 調査中</div></footer>'
      },

      {
        pos: {
          lat: 37.649544835658,
          lng: 140.94360351562503
        },
        title: "福島県12例目",
        icon: 'image/inpatient_icon4.04.png',
        infoWindowOpen: false,
        infoWindowContent: '<head><a id="num_start" href="https://www.mhlw.go.jp/content/10906000/000618993.pdf">福島県12例目</a></head><body><strong><div class="container"><div class="item">・4/04</div><div class="item">福島県発表 / 相双保健所管内居住</div></div></strong><div class="container"><div class="item">&nbsp;※追記</div><div class="item">無症状 / 福島県9例目の濃厚接触者</div></div></body><footer><div><span style=color:black>現在 </span>入院中</div><div id="num_end"><span style=color:black>濃厚接触者</span> 調査中</div></footer>'
      },

      {
        pos: {
          lat: 37.130652,
          lng: 140.216623
        },
        title: "福島県13例目",
        icon: 'image/inpatient_icon4.04.png',
        infoWindowOpen: false,
        infoWindowContent: '<head><a id="num_start" href="https://www.mhlw.go.jp/content/10906000/000618994.pdf">福島県13例目</a></head><body><strong><div class="container"><div class="item">・4/04</div><div class="item">福島県発表 / 県南保健所管内居住</div></div></strong><div class="container"><div class="item">&nbsp;※追記</div><div class="item">発熱、咽頭痛、倦怠感、嗅覚異常症状 / 発症日3/30</div></div></body><footer><div><span style=color:black>現在 </span>入院中</div><div id="num_end"><span style=color:black>濃厚接触者</span> 調査中</div></footer>'
      },

      {
        pos: {
          lat: 37.38887601375841,
          lng: 140.3482818603516
        },
        title: "福島県14例目 (郡山市2例目)",
        icon: 'image/inpatient_icon4.04.png',
        infoWindowOpen: false,
        infoWindowContent: '<head><a id="num_start" href="https://www.mhlw.go.jp/content/10906000/000618995.pdf">福島県14例目 (郡山市2例目)</a></head><body><strong><div class="container"><div class="item">・4/04</div><div class="item">福島県発表 / 郡山市保健所管内居住</div></div></strong><div class="container"><div class="item">&nbsp;※追記</div><div class="item">呼吸苦、発熱症状 / 発症日4/02 (深夜) / 4/01に眼科手術のため、市内の医療機関に入院し、4/02の18時30分ごろに退院</div></div></body><footer><div><span style=color:black>現在 </span>入院中</div><div id="num_end"><span style=color:black>濃厚接触者</span> 調査中</div></footer>'
      }
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide the URL of the page. Otherwise, it is difficult to help you.